# "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" nginx-ingress controller does not overwrite X-Forwarded-Proto: http, X-Forwarded-Scheme: http

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

We are using an IAP, GCP L7 Loadbalancer with nginx-ingress controller (version 0.49.3). We deployed self-hosted GitLab and we are getting "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

After some intense days of trouble shooting we noticed that

```
POST /api/v4/jobs/request HTTP/1.1
Host: gitlab.ci.g.nakhoda.ai
X-Request-ID: dfa874d97ed06e0e7a7cf17c0a4ae2c0
X-Real-IP: 35.191.12.183
X-Forwarded-For: 35.191.12.183
X-Forwarded-Host: gitlab.ci.g.nakhoda.ai
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Scheme: http
X-Scheme: http
X-Original-Forwarded-For: 62.189.73.245, 35.186.225.221
Content-Length: 714
User-Agent: gitlab-runner 15.6.1 (15-6-stable; go1.18.8; linux/amd64)
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 4efdd65224a5882999fd0fb26a888bfd/2273898499790060164
Via: 1.1 google
```

X-Forwarded-Proto: http and X-Forwarded-Scheme: http it is set to `http` in our initial redirects. After fiddling with it a bit we executed in the container of the nginx-ingress-controller and edited the `nginx.conf` to have https for both of them and also added annotation `ssl-redirect: false`.

Afterwards the request looks like this:

```
POST /api/v4/jobs/request HTTP/1.1
Host: gitlab.ci.g.nakhoda.ai
X-Request-ID: f103bba96d47527dae15087d1dd1d476
X-Real-IP: 35.191.12.180
X-Forwarded-For: 35.191.12.180
X-Forwarded-Host: gitlab.ci.g.nakhoda.ai
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Scheme: https
X-Scheme: http
X-Original-Forwarded-For: 194.203.216.4, 35.186.225.221
Content-Length: 714
User-Agent: gitlab-runner 15.6.1 (15-6-stable; go1.18.8; linux/amd64)
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 3ceb1d9d95fa28be4da929dea1f3ac95/3016269448751760533
Via: 1.1 google
```

By manually editing now we can access GitLab without any issues but the problem is that this is a manual fix we added so every time a pipeline will do a deployment this will be reset in place.

The issue is that we looked for adding custom headers to overwrite the [nginx.conf](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-headers/ is not overwriting the normal nginx.conf configuration) but after adding a ConfigMap with the specific things or just adding similar annotations like this to the Ingress of the nginx-ingress controller or to the ConfigMap:

Gitlab Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gitlab-chart-webservice-default
  namespace: gitlab
  labels:
    app: webservice
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: webservice-6.6.2
    gitlab.com/webservice-name: default
    heritage: Helm
    release: gitlab-chart
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.provider: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: gitlab-chart
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: gitlab
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 512m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: '15'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '600'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 1.1.1.1
      - ip: 1.1.1.1
spec:
  ingressClassName: stable-protected
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - gitlab.ci.example.com
      secretName: gitlab-cert
  rules:
    - host: gitlab.ci.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gitlab-chart-webservice-default
                port:
                  number: 8181
```

ConfigMap for nginx controller

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: ingress-stable-protected
  annotations:
    refresh-me: |
      This 'refresh-me' annotation is purely used as a placeholder so we can
      modify its value in order to manually force the nginx ingress-controller
      to reload its configuration.
      Reload.
data:
  enable-vts-status: 'true'
  hide-headers: Strict-Transport-Security
  hsts: 'true'
  hsts-include-subdomains: 'false'
  hsts-preload: 'false'
  proxy-body-size: 2048m
  proxy-buffer-size: 16k
  proxy-connect-timeout: '5'
  proxy-next-upstream: 'off'
  proxy-read-timeout: '600'
  proxy-send-timeout: '600'
  server-name-hash-bucket-size: '256'
  server-tokens: 'false'
```

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-proto=https
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-scheme=https
```

It still takes the nginx.conf `http` so we are kind of stuck with this temporary fix.

Tried to add a bunch of custom headers and x-forwarded-headers as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was after version 0.24.0 of nginx-ingress there was a change for an annotation so by adding the following to the nginx configmap there is no more error.

A more deep description can be found in this [ticket](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3826)

```yaml
use-forwarded-headers: "true"
use-proxy-protcol: "false"
```

Full example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  enable-vts-status: "true"
  hide-headers: Strict-Transport-Security
  hsts-preload: "false"
  proxy-body-size: 2048m
  proxy-buffer-size: 16k
  proxy-connect-timeout: "5"
  proxy-next-upstream: "off"
  proxy-read-timeout: "600"
  proxy-send-timeout: "600"
  server-name-hash-bucket-size: "256"
  server-tokens: "false"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  use-proxy-protcol: "false"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    refresh-me: |
      This 'refresh-me' annotation is purely used as a placeholder so we can
      modify its value in order to manually force the nginx ingress-controller
      to reload its configuration.
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: pulumi
  name: nginx
  namespace: namespace
```